# Federated learning

Tags: python, dataset, federated-learning

I have two kinds of covid 19 datasets as two clients (the first one ST Scan images and the second is XRays images) and I use federated learning approch.
The question is can I use those dataset as two clients although they have different type to acheive the heterogeneity and try to solve it ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help/on-topic]. Try [stats.se] or [datascience.se].

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking when it comes to heterogeneity we think directly to use some personalization methods, you can use a neural network for your federated learning approach and when it comes to retrain your model locally try to find some layers which are user specific (lower layer for specific features for example) keep them on device do not send them for updating the global model.
in this case just the upper layer will be trained collaboratively :)